# How to NOT use dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have a small table view, maybe 10 items max, and I do not want to use the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` method. The reason is, each time I'm scrolling the table view, I have the first row in place of the last row, which take few second to update back to get update back with the last row.

I'm using a prototype cell and i try to remove the :

```
JsonTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

but it return blank cells in table view.

So here is my code :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

JsonTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell=[[JsonTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
          UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
```

I also try to keep the

```
JsonTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

and configure the cell like:

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell.title.text = titleStrip;
}
```

but in this case, I've got the prototype cell as it is in the storyboard. It's not blank, but not filled with data.

Anybody can tell me what I am doing wrong?

UPDATE **** 10.10.2014  *******

Here is maybe the all code would help :

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return myObject.count;
}
```

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
  static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

  JsonTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  if (cell == nil) {
      cell=[[JsonTableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:
          UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
  }

  dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);
  dispatch_async(queue, ^{

  NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

  NSMutableString *text;
  text = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
          [tmpDict objectForKeyedSubscript:title]];

  NSMutableString *detail;
  detail = [NSMutableString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",
            [tmpDict objectForKey:content]];

  NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tmpDict objectForKey:thumbnail]];
  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
  UIImage *img = [[UIImage alloc]initWithData:data];

  NSString *titleStrip = [[text description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""withString:@""];

  NSString *detailStrip = [[detail description] stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@""withString:@""];

  dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

  cell.titreNews.text = titleStrip;

  cell.detailNews.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;

  cell.detailNews.text = detailStrip;

  UIImage *image0 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"video.png"];

  if (img != nil) {
      cell.imageNews.image = img;
  }
  else {
      cell.imageNews.image = image0;
  }

  });
  });

  [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];

  return cell;
  }

Comment: You cannot NOT dequeue a prototype cell created in Storyboards. The reason your last row is showing stale data is because if this part of your code: `if (cell == nil) { cell.title.text = titleString }`. This means you are only setting the cell title text IF a new cell was allocated (essentially skipping any of the dequeued ones). Get rid of that check for nil and you should be good to go.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your help, but it doesn't work either

Answer (score 3):

First of all, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Second, I ***highly*** recommend against disabling dequeuing.  Apple is famously strict when it comes to expected behaviors, and trying to re-work a basic UI element like a TableView to work in a different way could easily get your app rejected.  Plus, dequeuing is a good thing, which helps keep memory usage down and streamlines things in general.  It's far, far better to find a way to design your own code so it works with the dequeuing process as it is intended to work.

That being said, as I understand it all you need to do is omit the `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` line, and it should work.  `cell` will be `nil` each time, and will thus get re-initialized each time from scratch.

Comment: Apple doesn't reject apps that don't dequeue table view cells. It's an entirely optional performance optimization.

Comment: @FruityGeek I agree entirely, my comment was simply suggesting caution around the mindset of altering suggested behavior. I provided the answer at the end because, in this particular instance, it's fine.

Comment: @Nerrolken thanks for you welcome, i know that dequeuing is not the best thing to do but having a cell which take few second to update when scrolling, is not very nice. I only have 10 cells so on a 4S you notice the problem quite often.

Answer (score 3):

This block of code is never called because you instantiate a cell before it (cell is never nil).

```
if (cell == nil) {
    cell.title.text = titleStrip;
}
```

Don't call the dequeue methods if you aren't using them. Change your method to this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    //Don't even try to dequeue, just create new cell instance
    JsonTableViewCell *cell = [[JsonTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.title.text = titleStrip;
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help to solve my problem, but it doesnot work for me. If i do that i got blank cell everywhere.